# Hide a HTML5 Canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, hide

I try to use the HTML5 Canvas tag, until now I managed to do what I wanted. But now I'm trying to hide in fade a Canvas element (context). The retunred error is `context.fadeOut is not a function`.

See my draft here: **http://jsfiddle.net/t46Ze/4/**

Thanks for your help.

---

**EDIT >** Here my initial wanted : [**http://jsfiddle.net/t46Ze/15/**](http://jsfiddle.net/t46Ze/15/)

**EDIT >** Here the Andrew proposition : [**http://jsfiddle.net/t46Ze/16/**](http://jsfiddle.net/t46Ze/16/) (with comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do exactly what you do to draw it, but in reverse,

http://jsfiddle.net/t46Ze/15/

Comment: I want to fade the circle, not all the Canvas.

Comment: That's good. That's what I wanted to do first but if the user leave the Canvas, their is a quick blink =/ That's why I want to try the fade effect.

Comment: But, if you do a goings-n-comings (quick enter&leave), the effect is down. Probably my bad coding.

Comment: @Jack easy fix, only update center if it is past a threshold, http://jsfiddle.net/t46Ze/8/

Comment: Yeah. Fine, really fluid. But less amazing than you previous example... I'll keep it anyway. Thanks a lot

Comment: yep. That my question answer. But you convince me with your expand/reduce example. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: (`I'll keep it anyway` I spoke about your idea ;)

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to fade out the 2D context of the canvas, not the canvas element itself. Fade out the element itself instead.

Comment: How can I only fade the circle? (not all the canvas)
That wat I want to do (to keep the bg canvas)

Comment: @JackNUMBER **THERE IS NO CIRCLE**. (Shouting for emphasis.) If Monet painted a circle on _his_ canvas and you asked him to 'fade it out' or 'move it', he'd hit you with his palette. The only way to change the canvas is to erase it and paint again with lower opacity.

Comment: Look ate the script and roll over the TEST text.

Comment: `erase it and paint again with` I forgot this way. F*cking jQuery automatisation =P Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do `$(canvas).fadeOut` instead of `context.fadeOut`

Comment: I want to fade the circle, not all the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try it with jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Path to your jQuery core js library or you can use one from Google.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" />
    <!-- Path to your jQuery UI js library or you can use one from Google.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js" />

</head>
<body>
   <canvas id="myCanvas" ..>..</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And when you want to fade it out, just call:

```
$("#myCanvas").fadeOut(2500); // 2 seconds and a half, for example
```

There are also other "effects" like:

```
$("#myCanvas").slideUp(1500); // 1 and a half seconds, for example
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code in the canvas

```
<canvas id="newCanvas" style="display: none"></canvas>
```